# Deploying files to remote machines

Tags: .net, file

I need to deploy a set of configuration files to a hundred or more Windows hosts.

I have the IP addresses, the user name and password, and the location on the remote machines into which the files should be copied - and was wondering if there was anything in the .NET framework that would let me utilise all that info to move these files?

Comment: What services are available on the remote machines?  File sharing, FTP?  Is there a firewall involved?  There has to be something running on the other end that's willing to talk to you and copy files on your behalf.  If there is, chances are the .Net Framework can help.

Comment: I'm not sure .NET would help with that. I've written a .NET app that allowed me to view running processes on anyone's machine within my network, but .NET doesn't allow you to tamper with them (prevents malicious use). I'm not totally sure, but I can only assume they would block something like adding config files to other machines, unless someone were there to accept them.

Comment: The remote machines are running Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition SP1, and all have Remote Desktop enabled. I'm not sure about FTP, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for powershell (assumes powershell v1.0 on your machine - doesn't have to be on servers):

```
-- begin info.csv --

ipaddress, username, password, path   (<- header)
1.2.3.4, foo, bar, "c:\temp"
5.6.7.8, dog, cat, "c:\temp\foo" 
...

-- end info.csv --
```

And here's a script which assumes the existance of the above CSV file in the same path.

```
import-csv info.csv | foreach-object {

    trap { 
       net use t: /delete
       continue
    }

    $root = "\\{0}\{1}" -f $_.ipaddress, ($_.path -replace ':', '$')
    net use t: $root $_.password /user:$_.username
    copy myconfig.config t:
    net use t: /delete
}
```

This came out of my head, so you might need to tweak it a little but you get the idea.

-Oisin

Comment: This looks like what I'm after. I've never used Powershell before, and I'm getting the following error from your example;

Copy-Item : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 't' does not exist.

Any ideas what might be causing that?

Cheers

Comment: this might sound like a retarded question, but are you using a _valid_ CSV file with real IP addresses and share names? If you test the "net use" command on its own, does it create the drive for you?

Comment: Yeah the CSV was valid. It actually turned out to be an unrelated network issue - the hosts were inaccessible from my dev machine, so the mapping to T: was producing the error above.

Got it working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If they're on your AD network, what we usually do is ask our Networking department to [deploy them via Group Policy](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Group-Policy-Deploy-Applications.html). Since you can build an installer in Visual Studio to install anything (it doesn't have to be an application), you could use this for configuration files as well.

Note: I have no experience with the network end of things. If this is a possibility you may want to ask the question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).